# Picturebox controls and memory

Tags: memory, vb.net-2010, picturebox

I am planning on using many pictureboxes as controls instead of e.g. buttons, mostly because the controls need to look like icons and not buttons.  Would pictureboxes kill memory too much when compared with buttons?   Is there a way to make a button appear as an icon instead of a picturebox, that is, can a button be made to look like a .png small icon image file instead of a button with no border?

Lastly, there will be several tabs available to the user via a tabcontrol, each of which has maybe 10-15 pictureboxes that can be clicked on.  Is there a shortcut for addhandler if many pictureboxes are used within a tab as a replacement for a buttonbar (no longer supported in VB.NET 2010)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button control SUPPORTS pictures already!
Most likely too (more importantly!) the buttonis LIGHTWEIGHT and will consume less memory than pictureboxes

Use the Property sheet to assign the image(s)
You can assign a different image for the button up and down states too!!

[image]